# WSDL soap v1 error: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: soap, xml

the complete error is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>1</faultcode>
         <faultstring>SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT `customer_entity`.* FROM `customer_entity` WHERE (entity_id =8, 'firstname => Matheus, lastname => teste')</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>    </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My request sending is simple, just a array with two resources:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">   
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:call>
         <sessionId>e4a9c70ae37dff4f4f27dbd0e1245s5s5s2b29</sessionId>
         <resourcePath>customer_address.create</resourcePath>
         <args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" enc:arrayType="rs:Resource[2]">
            <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
              <item  xsi:type="rs:Resource">
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">customerId</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:int">8</value>
            </item>
              <item  xsi:type="rs:Resource">
              <key xsi:type="enc:Array">addressdata</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:array">firstname => Matheus, lastname => teste</value>
            </item>
            </item>
        </args>
      </ns1:call>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So.... 
as I understand it must send the request only 1 ITEM with the value of the customerId and the array values addressdata as link http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customerAddress/customer_address.create.html But I am sent with XML and my code above does not work, someone could say why? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved changing the value

```
<args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
```

to ....

```
<args SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
```

and separate the 2 types of array in single item